# Error and Array not working in PowerShell script in Azure AutomationAccount

Tags: powershell, office365, azure-automation

Good morning, I am creating a Script to create and update my Office365 users but it is giving me the following error:

Error occurred while executing GetUsers
Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'userPrincipalName' of resource 'User'.
RequestId: 39641b2a-8464-4fa1-950b-f6fec0294175
DateTimeStamp: Mon, 05 Sep 2022 06:59:23 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed

The Array is not working to.

This is my code (I'm sorry for putting so much code but I can't identify the error.):

```
<#
    Description => Create new users and update ALL data of existing users. Ups and downs.
#>
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [array] $Datos
)

<#Param(
    [array] $Datos
)#>

#Datos = @()

# Get the credential from Automation  
$credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'powershell'  
#$userName = $credential.UserName
#$securePassword = $credential.Password
$userName = "UserName"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Password" -Force
  
$psCredential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $userName, $securePassword

#$Session = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid -Credential $Credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
$Session = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid -Credential $psCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession -Session $Session -DisableNameChecking:$true -AllowClobber:$true | Out-Null
#Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $psCredentia

# Connect to Microsoft AzureAD & Teams  
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $psCredential
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $psCredential
#Connect-AzureAD -Credential $userName $securePassword
#Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $userName $securePassword

<# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#>
<# ----           INICIO DEL FOREACH                                                                                  ----#>
<# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#>
ForEach ($Linea in $Datos) {

    # Get the Parameters >>> User,Pass,Estado,AzureAD,Nom,Aps,Email,Puesto,Departamento,Empresa,Dni,Pais,Movil,Matricula,Email_Pro,Emai_Padre,Email_Madre,Tutor,Curso_Escolar
    $CharArray =$Linea.Split(",")
    $User = $CharArray[0]
    $Pass = $CharArray[1]
    $Estado = $CharArray[2]
    $AzureAD = $CharArray[3]
    $Nom = $CharArray[4]
    $Aps = $CharArray[5]
    $Email = $CharArray[6]
    $Puesto = $CharArray[7]
    $Departamento = $CharArray[8]
    $Empresa = $CharArray[9]
    $Dni = $CharArray[10]
    $Pais = $CharArray[11]
    $Movil = $CharArray[12]
    $Matricula = $CharArray[13]
    $Email_Pro = $CharArray[14]
    $Emai_Padre = $CharArray[15]
    $Email_Madre = $CharArray[16]
    $Tutor = $CharArray[17]
    #$Curso_Escolar = $CharArray[18]
    $DisplayName = -join($CharArray[4]," ",$CharArray[5])
    $UserPrincipalName = $CharArray[6]
    $Email_Tutor = -join($CharArray[17],"@example.es")
    
    $UserID = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userPrincipalName'"| Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty ObjectID

<# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#>
<# ----           Comprobar si Existe o no el usuario  y que hacer con el en AzureAD                                  ----#>
<# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#>
    if($UserID){
        
        $EstadoAD = Get-mailbox -identity $UserPrincipalName | Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty CustomAttribute1      # ALTA
        #$DepartamentoAD    = Get-mailbox -identity $UserPrincipalName | Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty CustomAttribute2        # Alumnos_1BX
        $MatriculaAD = Get-mailbox -identity $UserPrincipalName | Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty CustomAttribute3       # BX1BYG;BX1DAR;BX1EFI;BX1FIL;BX1FYQ;BX1CAS;BX1CAT;BX1ING;BX1MAT;BX1TUT;BX1VOL
        #$PuestoAD = Get-mailbox -identity $UserPrincipalName | Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty CustomAttribute4     # BX1B
        #$Curso_EscolarAD = Get-mailbox -identity $UserPrincipalName | Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty CustomAttribute5      # 2022-2023
        #$Email_PropioAD = Get-mailbox -identity $UserPrincipalName | Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty CustomAttribute6       # 
        #$Email_PadreAD = Get-mailbox -identity $UserPrincipalName | Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty CustomAttribute7        # 
        #$Email_MadreAD = Get-mailbox -identity $UserPrincipalName | Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty CustomAttribute8        # 
        
        #$UserID = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "Mail eq $Email"| Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty ObjectID  

        if ($MatriculaAD -ne $Matricula){
            # Si cambia la Matricula...
            $Accion = "Actualizar"
        }   
        else{
            if ($Estado -ne $EstadoAD){
                switch ($Estado){
                    "ALTA"{
                        $Accion = "Alta"
                        break
                    }
                    "BAJA"{
                        $Accion = "Baja"
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                $Accion = "Existe"
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $User = $User.ToString()
        if ($AzureAD -eq 'SI'){
            $Accion = "Nuevo"
        }
        else{
            $Accion = "Nada"
        }
    }
<# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#>
<# ----           Acciones sobre usuario : Nuevo/Alta/Baja/Actualizar/Nada                                            ----#>
<# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#>
switch ($Accion ){
    "Nuevo"{
        Write-Output "Nuevo => $Accion  - $User"
        if($Estado -eq "ALTA") {
            $PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile 
            $PasswordProfile.Password = $Pass
            New-AzureADUser -DisplayName $DisplayName -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -UserPrincipalName $userPrincipalName -AccountEnabled $true -GivenName $Nom -Surname $Aps -MailNickName $User -UsageLocation 'ES' 
            Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserPrincipalName -JobTitle $Puesto -Department $Departamento -CompanyName $Empresa -PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName $Estado
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute1 $Estado
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute2 $Departamento
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute3 $Matricula
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute4 $Puesto 
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute5 "2022-2023" $Curso_Escolarolar
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute6 $Email_Pro
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute7 $Emai_Padre
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute8 $Email_Madre
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute9 "ENVIAR"
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute10 $DisplayName
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute11 $Email_Tutor
            Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute12 $Pass
        }   
        ; break
    }
    "Actualizar"{
        Write-Output "Actualizar => $Accion - $User"
        Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute3 $Matricula
        ; break
    }
    "Alta"{
        Write-Output "Actualizar => $Accion - $User"
        $PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile 
        $PasswordProfile.Password = $Pass
        Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $userPrincipalName -DisplayName $DisplayName -AccountEnabled $true -GivenName $Nom -Surname $Aps -UsageLocation 'ES'
        Set-AzureADUserPassword -ObjectId  $UserID -Password $PasswordProfile
        Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute1 $Estado
        Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute3 $Matricula
        Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute6 $Email_Pro
        Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute9 "ENVIAR"
        Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute10 $DisplayName
        Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute11 $Email_Tutor
        Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute12 $Pass
        ; break
    }
    "Baja"{
        Write-Output "Baja => $Accion - $User"
        Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $userPrincipalName -AccountEnabled $false
        <#Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute1 $Estado#>
        Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipalName -CustomAttribute1 "BAJA"
        ; break
    }
    "Existe"{
        Write-Output "El usuario $Accion - $User => Estado actual: $Estado"
        ; break
    }
    "Nada"{
        Write-Output "No hacer $Accion => $AzureAD crear en Azure AD => $User"
        ; break
    }
}
<# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#>
<# ----           Profesores => Añadir y Quitar Teams                                                                 ----#>
<# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#>
if ($Departamento -eq 'Empleados_Profesores'){
    Write-Output "##########################################################"

    ForEach ($MatAD in $MatArrayAD){
        $Accion = '---'
        $IdGrupo = "---"
        if ($Matricula -match $MatAD){
            $Accion = 'YA Matriculado'
        }
        else{
            $IdGrupo = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "Mail eq '$MatAD@test.es'"| Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty ObjectID
            if ($IdGrupo){
                $Accion = 'Borrar'          
                Remove-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $IdGrupo -OwnerId $UserID
                Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $IdGrupo -MemberId $UserID
            }
        }
        Write-Output "$User     $Accion en  $MatAD  =>  $IdGrupo"
    }
    Write-Output "----------------------------------------------------------"
    ForEach ($Mat in $MatArray){
        $Accion = '---'
        $IdGrupo = "---"
        if ($MatriculaAD -match $Mat){
            $Accion = 'YA Matriculado'
        }
        else{
            $IdGrupo = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "Mail eq '$Mat@test.es'"| Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty ObjectID
            if ($IdGrupo){
                $Accion = 'Matricular'
                Add-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $IdGrupo -RefObjectId $UserID
            }
        }
            Write-Output "$User     $Accion en  $Mat    =>  $IdGrupo"
    }
    Write-Output "----------------------------------------------------------"
    
}
<# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#>
<# ----           FIN DEL FOREACH                                                                                     ----#>
<# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#>
}

# Disconnect from Microsoft Teams  
Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams 
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

The error seems to be that i need to doble quote '$userPrincipalName'. But it seem that the Array is not getting filled.

What @Toni said is not working for me, my array is still not working.

Update 6/9/2022

Changed this:

```
$UserID = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userPrincipalName'"| Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty ObjectID
```

For this:

```
$UserID = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq ''$userPrincipalName''"| Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty ObjectID
```

The first error is solved, but my Array is still not working.

Comment: probably an issue with the value of the variable '$userPrincipalName' - it may contain single quotes which need to be escaped by doubling them

Comment: @Toni Tha solved the error, but it seems that the Array is not getting filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, first as discussed you need to escape single quotes in the UPN, e.g.:

```
$userPrincipalName = $userPrinicpalName -replace "'","''"
```

then it looks like you are specifying the wrong attribute name and I also guess there is no need to expand, your code:

```
$UserID = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userPrincipalName'"| Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty ObjectID

change to:
$UserID = (Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userPrincipalName'").id
```

But be aware that the Variable $UserId contains only the Id, nothing else.

Check your code, you have the same issue several times, e.g.:

```
Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "Mail eq '$Mat@test.es'"| Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty ObjectID
```

I am using the microsoft.graph module not the AZmodule like you. But the attribute names should be the same. So the parameters are named ObjectId, userId and so on but the attribute on the object is simply called Id.

Ok that's quite a different thing that the array $Datos is empty. This is an input parameter for the script and does not get filled by the script. So your issue is not within this script, the problem is related to the call of the script and passing the array to the parameter Datos. This has nothing to do with the code posted here....

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now i need to see why my array is empty.

Comment: thats because of: Select-Object ObjectId -ExpandProperty ObjectID - there is sinply not attribute called ObjectId. Its called Id.

Comment: I think its a problem from Power Automate, because i have all the data in Power BI

Comment: if you output this for one user: Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userPrincipalName'" is the attribute then called objecId or Id?

Comment: its callet objectid

Comment: The script worked since i changed the account pass on Friday. Now im haveing this problems.

Comment: ok interesting, did not expect that the cmdlets do return other attribute names than those specified in the directory. anyways.... hehe Ok you changed the pwd, but as you are receiving data this should be fine... which array does not contain the expected result?

Comment: this array should be getting the users to create them

Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [array] $Datos
)

i get the list of users from Power Bi.